# Скрипт перевода числа в разные системы счисления

Tags: скрипт, php

Как реализовать скрипт на php, чтобы переводить число из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную и обратно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[decbin](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_decbin.asp)

> decbin() преобразует десятичное число в двоичное число.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужны любые системы счисления, то вам поможет функция [base_convert()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_base_convert.asp).